# Sheaves for a Grothendieck topology compatible with a pretopology

Tags: sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topologies

$ \newcommand{\cat}[1]{\mathcal{#1}} $ Let $ (\cat C,J) $ be a site. I'm trying to show that if the topology $ J $ comes from a pretopology $ K $ in the sense that for each $ X\in \cat C $ and for each covering sieve $ S\in J(X) $, there exists some covering $ k = \{U_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i} X\}_{i\in I}\in K(X) $ of $ X $ such that $ k\in S $, then the $  J $-sheaves are exactly the $ K $-sheaves.

I recall some definitions. A presheaf $ F\colon \cat C^\mathrm{op}\to \mathrm{Set} $ is a *$ J $-sheaf* if for any $ X\in \cat C $, for any covering sieve $ S\in J(X) $ and for any matching family $ \sigma\colon S\to F $, there exists a unique morphism of presheaves $ h_X\to F $ such that the obvious diagram commutes, where $ h_X = \cat C({-},X) $. On the other hand, $ F $ is a *$ K $-sheaf* if for each $ X\in \cat C $, for each covering $ \{U_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i} X\}_{i\in I}\in K(X) $ and for each family of sections $ s_{\phi_i}\in F(U_i) $ such that the obvious compatibility condition holds, there exists a unique $ s\in F(X) $ that is compatible with the $ s_\phi $s once "restricted".

To show the implication "$ J $-sheaf implies $ K $-sheaf" I noticed that I need the following condition to hold: given an object $ X\in \cat C $ and a covering $ k = \{U_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i} X\}_{i\in I}\in K(X) $, the sieve $ S_k $ of all the arrows $ U\xrightarrow f X $ that factors through some $ \phi $ is again a $ J $-covering sieve.

Is it always the case? Or is it the case that the theorem I'm trying to prove is false?

Comment: Are you sure that you interpreted correctly the condition “$J$ comes from $K$”? All it seems to tell me is that every $J$-covering can be refined to a $K$-covering, which gives only one inclusion between $J$ and the topology defined by $K$… the “other” condition seems to be related to the other inclusion.

Comment: So are you claiming that in the case where $ J $ is strictly larger than the topology generated by $ K $, then the theorem I'm trying to prove could be false? Good to know.

Comment: Consider the case of a classical space: say, $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete or the Archimedian topology. They don’t have the same sheaves, right?

Comment: Yeah, what I meant yesterday is that it could happen not every sieve on $ X\in \mathcal C $ that contains some $ k\in K(X) $ is actually a $ J $-covering sieve of $ X $.